# Vue-auth accessing $auth inside vuex actions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-cli

I'm using Vue-auth package for authentication of my vue-cli application.
Everything is working fine but when I'm accessing this code in my vue actions it returns `undefined`. any idea?

```
const AuthService = {
    test(data) {
        console.log(this.$auth)
    },
}
```

Package:
https://github.com/websanova/vue-auth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the auth instance of the package at Vue.auth property.

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const AuthService = {
    test(data) {
        console.log(Vue.auth)
    },
}
```